# React Native app crash on passing image uri

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Everything was working fine before I uninstalled the app then reinstall using `npx react-native run-android`.
I'm sure that I imported the right Image component from react-native and it only happens when passing uri from some specific domain (e.g unsplash) which was working fine in the previous build. I can't figure out what went wrong because it just crashes without any message.

Comment: can you add some code, like how you passed the image ?

Comment: As I said, it only crashes when I use uri from some specific domain. I guess those are the domains that I used in the previous build. Example ```<Image source={{uri: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e0/7c/3b/e07c3baea2c410f09d2c175d92982fe8.png'}}/>``` -> works  ```<Image source={{uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1624973419141-739e19a26793?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=701&q=80'}}/>``` -> not work

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have prohibited characters in your uri ?
You can try by using [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) before.

I will try to reproduce your error tonight and come back to detail my answer if I find a solution.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem because my app was running fine before I reinstall it. By the way I don't know if running ```gradlew clean``` was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the latest version of `@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps`. I solved it by downgrading the version to 8.1.0.